# How did Bond know about Mathis on Casino Royale?

Tags: james-bond, casino-royale

When James Bond wins the poker bet, he and Vesper go to dinner. Her phone rings two times, and in the latter, she says that Mathis needs her.

After a moments that she leaves, Bond thought that something was wrong from the fact that Mathis send the text, and goes after her, to see her capture and start pursuing. He crashes the car, Le Chiffre captures him and says:

> Your friend Mathis, was really my friend Mathis.

But how Bond drew the conclusion that Vesper would be captured from the fact that Mathis called her? Nowhere in the movie indicates that Mathis is a traitor.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This scene appears in the [source novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casino_Royale_(novel)) by Ian Fleming, albeit with a paper note rather than an SMS.

> *At four o'clock Bond was about to call for the bill when the maitre d'hotel appeared at their table and inquired for Miss Lynd. He handed her a note which she took and read hastily.
>
>   'Oh, it's only Mathis,' she said. 'He says would I come to the entrance hall. He's got a message for you. Perhaps he's not in evening clothes or something. I won't be a minute. Then perhaps we could go home.'*
>
> ...
>
> *Suddenly the note to Vesper seemed odd to him. It was not the way
>   Mathis would do things. He would have asked them both to join him at
>   the bar of the Casino or he would have joined them in the night-club,
>   whatever his clothes. They would have laughed together and Mathis
>   would have been excited. He had much to tell Bond, more than Bond had
>   to tell him. The arrest of the Bulgarian, who had probably talked some
>   more; the chase after the man with the stick; Le Chiffre's movements
>   when he left the Casino.*

It's also pretty notable that while Vesper and Mathis are both ostensibly on the same side and share a mutual contact (Bond) there's no obvious reason why he'd be touching base with her instead of him. This explains the second part of your question; **Bond is leaving the restaurant, not specifically to follow Vesper but to go and see Mathis**.

When added to the fact that he's still trying to puzzle out how his ability to read Le Chiffre's "tell" failed (something that only Vesper and Mathis could have disclosed) it all seems a bit suspicious and certainly worthy of his attention.

For the record, he probably would have realised all of this sooner if he hadn't **nearly died** a few hours ago.